# HTML form run javascript on enter?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am building a newtab page here:

http://codepen.io/Thisisntme/full/VvgeyV

This page consists of a pretty design thing, and a google search bar. However, when I press enter, rather than searching google it opens the same window with `http://codepen.io/Thisisntme/full/VvgeyV?inputbox=TEST_INPUT`  ("TEST_INPUT" being whatever was typed into the box).

When I press the submit button off to the left, It actually searches.

How can I make this search when the enter key is pressed?

Here is the code important to the form.

HTML:

```
<form NAME="myform">
  <div id = "textbox">
   <INPUT type="text" name="inputbox" value="" placeholder="Search with me!">
  </div>
   <input type="button" name="button" value="Click" onClick="google(this.form)">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#backgroundstuff canvas {
   outline: 0px;
   position: fixed;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   /*width: auto;
   height: 100%;*/

   z-index: -99;
}
```

Javascript

```
function google(form) {
   var gSearch = form.inputbox.value;
   window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + gSearch;
   //window.location.replace('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + gSearch);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The enter key automatically submits the form.

If you do not have an `action` defined on your form, it will default to the same page.

The posted data will use the `name` parameter of your form fields.

Using proper form markup will solve both issues.

- Setting an `action`:

  ```
  <form method="GET" action="https://www.google.com/search">
  ```
- Setting `name` to the name of the parameter you want to pass:

  ```
  <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search with me!">
  ```

With both of these taken care of, you won't need the `google` function. Your "search" button can be a simple submit:

```
<input type="submit" value="Click">
```

Comment: This is better and simpler than anything else including my answer here!

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! Will accept in a few minutes. This works with any "?var=" things in a url, right?

Comment: Well this is exactly the kind of task that html forms were designed to do. @10Replies: Yes, when using `method="GET"` (which is also default, if you omit method entirely) the data will be posted as a querystring in the format `name=value` for any non-disabled form fields.

Comment: @10Replies Yes, it will. GET requests are passed through those.

Answer (score 2):

change your html to:

```
<form NAME="myform" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); google(this)">
  <div id = "textbox">
   <INPUT type="text" name="inputbox" value="" placeholder="Search with me!">
  </div>
   <input type="submit" name="button" value="Click">
</form>
```

So that it works on the submit of the form not on the click of the button.

Also make sure to cancel the event, like Juan Mendes showed below.

Comment: Change your `button` for a `input type='submit'` and then it will work on both enter and click.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
<form onsubmit="return google(this)">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And change your `google` function to:

```
function google(form) {
   // YOUR LOGIC HERE
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This way you can implement search results based on keyboard click.

$( "#txtBox" ).keypress(function( event,value ) { if ( event.which == 13 ) { var gSearch = form.inputbox.value; window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + gSearch; } });

Answer (score 0):

When you hit enter, it submits the form and reloads the page. You need to listen to the form `submit` event instead of the click. Then you can call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from being submitted.

```
<form NAME="myform" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); google(this)">
```

However, you don't need JavaScript, just the `action` attribute of the form to be `https://www.google.com/search` and make the text field's name be "q"

```
<form NAME="myform" method="GET" action="https://www.google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search with me!">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a form pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> will launch an [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).
This event is what submits your request and reloads the page.

To make it go to google instead you should start by capturing the event and making sure it doesn't bubble up or do anything by default.

To do this, simply add an `id` to your form and capture the event e.g.

`<form name="myform" id="to_cancel_submit">`

then in your JS, target the element here

`form = document.getElementById('to_cancel_submit')`

after you have the form in a variable (or directly, doesn't matter) you bind the [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) handler for it and prevent the default events like this

```
form.submit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // pretty obvious
    e.cancelBubble(); // prevents bubbling to parents
    return false; // both of the above

    // call your functions here...
}
```